# Nested IF statements in Excel using Dates

Tags: excel, nested

Ive searched far and wide on Stackoverflow, and I cannot seen to locate my question. I clearly am having an issue with the nested IF statement, but i cannot find any reference question to duplicate my situation.

Here is what I am "trying" to do.

```
"Received" Cell H3 = 12/10/2017
"Start Date" Cell I3 = 12/15/2017
"Finish Date" Cell K3 = 12/20/2017
```

"Status" Cell J3 is where I want the following options to show up.

If Date present in H3 (Received), show "Bare". If Date shown in I3 (Start Date) Greater/Later than H3 (Received Date), show "In Process". If Date shown in K3 (Finish Date) is Greater/Later than I3 (Start Date, then J3 should reflect "Completed". If nothing shown in H3 (Received), show Nothing in J3.

This is the string that I am using, and it works in all aspects EXCEPT it doesn't show "Completed" when I add the "Finish Date" in. Since it works kinda, but not all the way is where I admit defeat. I need an error to chase if I am doing to diagnose with any luck lol

```
=IF(H3<>"",IF(I3>H3,"IN PROCESS",IF(K3>I3,"COMPLETED","BARE")))
```

ANY Help would be appreciated, im sure its probably something rather simple in regards to my eye not seeing a comma... but if im way off im eager to learn! 
Thanks in advance. 
JH

Comment: It will only hit `IF(K3>I3,"COMPLETED","BARE")` if `I3>H3` if false anyway.  I look at your data, and I3 is greater than H3. 12/15 is after 12/10. So I would expect it to show "IN PROCESS", no matter what the finish data is. Maybe you just need to be nesting your 3rd conditional here inside of the true case of your second conditional, not the false case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF (H3 <> "", IF (K3 > I3, "COMPLETED", IF (I3>H3, "IN PROCESS", "BARE")))
```

Comment: It wont let me Upvote this, as Im a new member... but I modified what you have provided here slightly to get the following. and it works perfectly. =IF(H3 <> "", IF(K3 > I3,"COMPLETED", IF(I3>H3, "IN PROCESS","BARE")),"")

Comment: I think you can mark the answer as correct even having a low score. And also delete the question if you think it won't help others, do as you like. I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the `Finished date` always be >= `Start Date` and `Start Date` >= `Received Date`?

If so then perhaps just count how many dates there are. If there's one date (Received) status is `BARE`, if there are two then `IN PROCESS`, if there are 3 it's `COMPLETED` (and no dates just returns a blank)

`=CHOOSE(COUNT(H3,I3,K3)+1,"","BARE","IN PROCESS","COMPLETED")`

Answer (score 0):

The logic as you've described it is kind of wonky. I think it's better to structure your statements like this:

1. If `K3` exists and `K3 > I3`, the status is `COMPLETE`
2. If `I3` exists and `I3 > H3`, the status is `IN PROGRESS`
3. If `H3` exists, the status is `RECEIVED`
4. Else the status is `BARE`

I believe that's what you're after. In that case, this algorithm satisfies that logic:

```
=IF(AND(K3<>"",K3>I3),"COMPLETED",IF(AND(I3<>"",I3>H3),"IN PROCESS",IF(H3<>"","RECEIVED","BARE")))
```